# PHP's DateTime::Diff "steals" one day

Tags: php, datetime

I want to calculate date difference between two days. Problem is that when I calculate days one day (current day) is missing from calculation.

Lets say that date1 is 20-12-2014 and date2 is 21-12-2014.
Results of DateTime::Diff using these two dates are 0 (I want to be 1, not zero)

Did I miss something bad or DateTime::Diff calculates date difference like i explained above?

Here is code that I am using (I want to display date difference in days):

```
      $currentDay = new DateTime();
        $listDay = new DateTime($results["date"]);//from mysql database (output is like 21-12-2014
        $interval = $currentDay->diff($listDay);
        $daysLeft=(int)$interval->format("%r%a");
```

Comment: `new DateTime()` will set $currentDay to the current date *and time*. You're probably seeing zero because there's actually less than a whole day between the current date and *time* and the date you're comparing it to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like @Matt already said in the comment, you are not only comparing dates, but dates with times, where in `$currentDay` variable you have time set to current time, and time in `$listDay` is set to `00:00:00`. You can quickly see that if you dump those 2 variables, like `print_r($currentDay);` and `print_r($listDay);`.

Solution would be, to create `$currentDay` DateTime object with time set to `00:00:00`, and this can easily accomplished with `today` keyword:

```php
$currentDay = new DateTime('today');
$listDay = new DateTime($results['date']);
$interval = $currentDay->diff($listDay);
echo $interval->format('%r%a');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/234479)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare two DateTime objects without taking into account the time. You can use the code below.

```
$diff = $currentDay->setTime(0,0)->diff($listDay->setTime(0,0))->days;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make very sure you're passing in 2 different dates because if you make 2 new DateTime objects that are 1 day apart, it will give you a difference of 1 day.  Also, you can shorten your last two lines to just one:

```
$daysLeft = $currentDay->diff($listDay)->days;
```